# How to share data between iPhones?

Tags: iphone, facebook, networking

This seems like a simple problem, but the more I plan it out, the harder it seems. The basic idea is this:

Person A wants to give person B permission to see his/her data on person B's device. Person A uses either person B's phone #, email, or Facebook info to send a request to person B. A has a unique ID for their device, but A does not know B's ID before the request. B might not have the app a well thus no account or ID exists.

What would be the best method for this handshake using phone #, email, or Facebook with a JSON, schemaless backend? I do have support for notifications, I'm just not sure how to properly and securely make the transfer so person A can have person B's ID to always send data to them in the future.

There are just so many factors, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Did you get that resolved? Would be interested how. Got a similar challenge as I would like to enable my app to share data (person A sends the data to persons Bs device).

Comment: It was pretty rough to be honest. I used Parse as my backend and hooked up my users using Facebook & email. I had an intermediate table for sharing. Each user had an array of user IDs that they were sharing with. I enabled push notifications so that when you shared with another person, they got a notification and an option to return sharing. Thus, each user had an array of people they wanted to share with. The sticky part was the handshake which I still don't like how I did. I basically check if each user has the other's user ID in their sharing array. In my opinion, its very sub optimal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty rough to be honest. I used Parse as my backend and hooked up my users using Facebook & email. I had an intermediate table for sharing. Each user had an array of user IDs that they were sharing with. I enabled push notifications so that when you shared with another person, they got a notification and an option to return sharing. Thus, each user had an array of people they wanted to share with. The sticky part was the handshake which I still don't like how I did. I basically check if each user has the other's user ID in their sharing array. In my opinion, its very sub optimal, but it works for now.